# How to use jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to replace jquery date picker which I have now with this one: https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker
What I need to change?

In my `functions.php` is this part of code:

```
function uep_admin_script_style( $hook ) {
    global $post_type;
if ( 'post.php' == $hook || 'post-new.php' == $hook ) {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'upcoming-competitions',
        SCRIPTS . 'script.js',
        array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ),
        '1.0',
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'jquery-ui-calendar',
        STYLES . 'jquery-ui.css',
        false,
        '1.10.4',
        'all'
    );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'uep_admin_script_style' );
```

And script.js contain this code

```
(function( $ ) {

$( '#uep-competition-start-date' ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ){
        $( '#uep-competition-end-date' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate', selectedDate );
    }
});
$( '#uep-competition-end-date' ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ){
        $( '#uep-competition-start-date' ).datepicker( 'option', 'maxDate', selectedDate );
    }
});
$( '#uep-competition-entries-deadline' ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ){
        $( '#uep-competition-entries-deadline' ).datepicker( 'option', selectedDate );
    }
});
$( '#uep-class-start-date' ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ){
        $( '#uep-class-start-date' ).datepicker( 'option', selectedDate );
    }
});
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need js datepicker then no need to keep that anymore. Use your desired plugin. Make sure your theme based on bootstrap latest version.

Comment: I need to use this https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker instead of old one

Comment: is your theme based on bootstrap?than you can use bootstrap datetimepicker. It will not effect your theme.

Comment: Yes it uses bootstrap, but I need to enque for wp-admin

Comment: if you want to enque script for admin only then you can use this code bellow:                                                                                                                          add_action('init', 'admin_only');

function admin_only() {

    if( !is_admin() )
        return;

    // filter assignemnts and such go here
}